# How to import daily files and run them in databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have daily files created in my Azure data lake with the name "`0_2020_01_21_20_02_44.avro`" the only thing that changes is the date and time, I would like to read the files by using variable for the date and wildcards for hours, minutes and seconds, I have tried with below code but it raises an error.

```
val pfdtm = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusDays(2)   
val fileDate =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM_dd").format(pfdtm)

pfdtm: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 2020-02-21T19:48:57.763Z
fileDate: String = 2020_02_21 



 val df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").
load("adl://powerb.azuredatalakestore.net/SD/eventhubspace/eventhub/0_${fileDate}_*_*_*.avro")
```

It raises an error,the path does not exist. I am using spark 2.4.3, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing string interpolation for **`${fileDate}`** in `.load` which is causing variable value not getting passed over.

To fix add **`.load(s"")`** instead of **`.load("")`**

```
val df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").
load(s"adl://powerb.azuredatalakestore.net/SD/eventhubspace/eventhub/0_${fileDate}_*_*_*.avro")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It was a headache for a couple of weeks.

Comment: Or else you could use string formatting. 
load("adl://...... %s.......".format(fileDate))